# Ui not loading linear layouts defined at the final part of xml

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have the following layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="PI 12343"
            android:id="@+id/proformo"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Cargo Shipped"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/shippingStatus" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="on07 oct 2015"
                android:id="@+id/shippingDate" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="PI 12345"
                android:id="@+id/invoiceNumber" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="on Dec 2016"
                android:id="@+id/invoiceDate" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Shipment Reference No :"

                android:id="@+id/shipment_ref_no_label" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="4312412412"
                android:id="@+id/shipment_ref_no_value" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="ETD:"
                android:id="@+id/etdLabel" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="24 oct 2015"
                android:id="@+id/etdValue" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="ETA:"
                android:id="@+id/etaLabel" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="09 dec 2014"
                android:id="@+id/etaValue" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:src="@drawable/dashboard"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="7">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="BioMass Pellets"
                    android:id="@+id/productName" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="Quantity: "
                        android:id="@+id/quantity_label" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="40mts"
                        android:id="@+id/quantity_value" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="Amount: "
                        android:id="@+id/amount_label" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="200 USD"
                        android:id="@+id/amount_value" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="Quantity: "
                        android:id="@+id/rate_label" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="40 USD"
                        android:id="@+id/rate_value" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Im trying to bring all texts within linear layout. When i try to do so, amount and rate text is not visible. Im using layout weight since I want this ui to be adaptable to various devices. What modification can be made so every contents will be visible?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in ScrollVIew?

Comment: Is there any space available on the screen?

Comment: what are the dimension of the image used in imageView4?

Comment: the dimension might be anything when it is loaded dynamically. How to handle such dynamic sizes?

Comment: Haven't tried wrapping within scrollview

Comment: @Stanly  I just wanted to know so I could see the proper layout on my screen.  Wasn't a requirement :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it seems you have an initial child linear layout (vertical) under your top parent that's doing nothing but holding the rest of the linear layouts, which the parent can do, so I removed that.

I've also changed all of your child linear layouts width from 'match_parent' to 'wrap_content' and that did the trick for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/proformo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="PI 12343"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/shippingStatus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:text="Cargo Shipped"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/shippingDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="on07 oct 2015" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/invoiceNumber"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="PI 12345"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/invoiceDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="on Dec 2016"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/shipment_ref_no_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Shipment Reference No :"

                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/shipment_ref_no_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="4312412412"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/etdLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ETD:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/etdValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="24 oct 2015"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/etaLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ETA:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/etaValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="09 dec 2014"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/productName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="BioMass Pellets"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/quantity_label"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Quantity: "
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/quantity_value"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="40mts"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/amount_label"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Amount: "
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/amount_value"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="200 USD"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/rate_label"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Quantity: "
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/rate_value"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="40 USD"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Explanation:  your first child LL had a height of wrap_content, but had children of it's own with heights of match_parent.  The issue there is that the parent's height hasn't been measured yet, so when you actually launch the activity, you're getting inaccurate parent/child measurements.

The total view size is small enough that I don't think a scroll view would do the trick for you.

LinearLayout children height set to match_parent:
[image: LinearLayout children height set to match_parent]

LinearLayout children height set to wrap_content:
[image: LinearLayout children height set to wrap_content]

Answer (score 0):

keep the width and height for the parent linearlayout of quantity_value as wrap_content. Like Below

```
 <LinearLayout  android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Quantity: "
                    android:id="@+id/quantity_label" />
```

Also use the ScrollView to complete layout so that your layout can scroll for small height devices.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ScrollView to wrap whole view and Height of each view to wrap_content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="PI 12343"
        android:id="@+id/proformo"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Cargo Shipped"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/shippingStatus" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="on07 oct 2015"
            android:id="@+id/shippingDate" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="PI 12345"
            android:id="@+id/invoiceNumber" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="on Dec 2016"
            android:id="@+id/invoiceDate" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Shipment Reference No :"

            android:id="@+id/shipment_ref_no_label" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="4312412412"
            android:id="@+id/shipment_ref_no_value" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="ETD:"
            android:id="@+id/etdLabel" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="24 oct 2015"
            android:id="@+id/etdValue" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="ETA:"
            android:id="@+id/etaLabel" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="09 dec 2014"
            android:id="@+id/etaValue" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:src="@drawable/dashboard"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="BioMass Pellets"
                android:id="@+id/productName" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Quantity: "
                    android:id="@+id/quantity_label" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="40mts"
                    android:id="@+id/quantity_value" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Amount: "
                    android:id="@+id/amount_label" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="200 USD"
                    android:id="@+id/amount_value" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Quantity: "
                    android:id="@+id/rate_label" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="40 USD"
                    android:id="@+id/rate_value" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: setting the height of the children to wrap_content would work without the scrollview

Comment: but the think is content of view is set dynamically there is chances to increase or decrease the size of content and image that's why scrollview required to wrap whole view

Comment: That's a possibility.  But considering the last 4 lines of text are equal in height to the imageview, I'm guessing the image will be about the height shown, maybe just a little bigger

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="PI 12343"
            android:id="@+id/proformo"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Cargo Shipped"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/shippingStatus" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="on07 oct 2015"
                android:id="@+id/shippingDate" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="PI 12345"
                android:id="@+id/invoiceNumber" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="on Dec 2016"
                android:id="@+id/invoiceDate" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Shipment Reference No :"

                android:id="@+id/shipment_ref_no_label" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="4312412412"
                android:id="@+id/shipment_ref_no_value" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="ETD:"
                android:id="@+id/etdLabel" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="24 oct 2015"
                android:id="@+id/etdValue" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="ETA:"
                android:id="@+id/etaLabel" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="09 dec 2014"
                android:id="@+id/etaValue" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="7">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="BioMass Pellets"
                    android:id="@+id/productName" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="Quantity: "
                        android:id="@+id/quantity_label" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="40mts"
                        android:id="@+id/quantity_value" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="Amount: "
                        android:id="@+id/amount_label" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="200 USD"
                        android:id="@+id/amount_value" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="Quantity: "
                        android:id="@+id/rate_label" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="40 USD"
                        android:id="@+id/rate_value" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

try this it is working fine..the reason is due to the height of a linear layout is set to match_parent and it hides the rest of the content